# Visdual Studio .NET C++: Se puede añadir como enlace (Add as link) un archivo?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

¿Alguien sabe si en Visual Studio se puede agregar un archivo existente como un Enlace (Add as link) en C++?

En C# sí se puede. El botón te permite elegir entre "Agregar" o "Agregar como vínculo". En cambio, en C++ sólo te permite "Agregar".

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Cuando agregas archivos a un proyecto de C++, el archivo no se mueve a ninguna carpeta, se queda en su ubicación original. Supongo que por eso no tienes la opción de agregar como vínculo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En C++ el botón "Agregar" realmente lo que hace es crear un enlace. A diferencia de C#, donde el botón "Agregar" realiza una copia del fichero seleccionado y lo guarda en la carpeta indicada del proyecto destino, desvinculando el nuevo fichero de su origen.

C# te permite escoger entre agregar o enlazar. C++ no: para agregar un fichero  como lo hace C# debemos copiarlo primero y luego agregarlo.